# How to unpublish on the Google Apps Marketplace?

Tags: admin, google-apps-marketplace

Seems like a simple question, right?

We've got a legacy app that's been on the Google Apps Marketplace for 3 years now. We're about to sunset the app, so we want to unpublish it from the Apps Marketplace. Problem is that on our vender profile, the 'Unpublish' option is inactive/grayed out.

Combed through the support docs, and emailed Google Apps developer support - but haven't found any info or received a response re: why this would be happening.

Does anyone have any insight into why we might be stuck with all our apps published, and unable to unpublish them (or create any new apps, for that matter)? Any idea how to get this app unpublished from the Apps Marketplace?

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsok74bs9yydo3z/Screenshot%202014-03-14%2014.51.08.png

Answer (score 1):

Google reformed the Google Apps Marketplace, so we can't publish any application on the old Google Apps Marketplace.I don't really know why, but they don't allow us unpublish too(I want to know how to unpublish too).

Please refer to https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/.

Anyway, the old Google Apps Marketplace's application will be unabled to be installed on September 30th.